# Creating filter with SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I am trying to create a filter with SQL queries but am having trouble with numeric values linking to other tables.

Every time I try to link to another table, it takes the same record and repeats it for every element in the other table.

For example, here is query:

> **SELECT** 
>  ELEMENTS.RID,TAXONOMIES.SHORT_DESCRIPTION,[type],ELEMENT_NAME,ELEMENT_ID,SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS.DESCRIPTION,namespace_prefix,datatype_localname
>   
>   **FROM**
>  ELEMENTS,SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS,TAXONOMIES,SCHEMAS,DATA_TYPES
>   **WHERE** 
>  ELEMENTS.TAXONOMY_ID = TAXONOMIES.RID   AND ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_SCHEMA_ID = SCHEMAS.RID 
>  AND
>   ELEMENTS.DATA_TYPE_ID = DATA_TYPES.RID 
>  
>   AND ELEMENTS.SUBSTITUTION_GROUP_ID = 0

The last line is the actual filtering criteria.

Here is an example result:
[image]

There should only be ONE result (Item has an RID of 0).  But it's repeating a copy of the one record for every result inside the substitution groups table (there's 4).

Here is my database schema for reference.  The lines indicate relationships between tables and the circles indicate the values I want:
[image]

Comment: Two things: 1) use INNER/OUTER JOIN in your query to clarify (for yourself at least) which you're doing; 2) I don't see a join to SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS even though you're pulling from that table. You need to add that.

Comment: Agreed, [please stop using this ancient, unmaintainable `FROM a,b,c` syntax](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgot to join between `ELEMENTS` and `SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS` in your query.

```
SELECT
ELEMENTS.RID,TAXONOMIES.SHORT_DESCRIPTION,[type],ELEMENT_NAME,ELEMENT_ID,SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS.DESCRIPTION,namespace_prefix,datatype_localname
FROM
ELEMENTS,SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS,TAXONOMIES,SCHEMAS,DATA_TYPES
WHERE
ELEMENTS.TAXONOMY_ID = TAXONOMIES.RID AND ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_SCHEMA_ID = SCHEMAS.RID
AND ELEMENTS.DATA_TYPE_ID = DATA_TYPES.RID
AND ELEMENTS.SUBSTITUTION_GROUP_ID = SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS.RID
AND ELEMENTS.SUBSTITUTION_GROUP_ID = 0
```

Comment: Ah I don't know how I missed that!.  But I get an error "[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "SUBSTITUTION_GROUP.RID" could not be bound."

Comment: @johnhannigan: sorry, typo..`SUBSTITUTION_GROUP` should be `SUBSTITUTION_GROUPS`. I just fixed my answer